# How to repent from lying?

Tags: tawba, lying

As everyone knows, lying is one of the great and major sins. Let's say, at some point, a person lied a small lie. How can he repent?
Does he need to tell whom he lied to the truth?
Or is it enough to do istighfar (repent)?

Comment: In the meanwhile, (as more information) to the best of my knowledge, persisting on a minor sin would make it to major sin. Besides I appreciate your constructive question which can be really helpful for the users as the sin which unfortunately can be done daily by many people. God Bless You, mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### In the name of Allah, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful

As you all probably know, lie is considered as a haram (forbidden) deed. As you pointed out regarding Tu’bah, the best way is repentance concerning that to make it up for the your previous mistakes.

As a brief answer for your constructive question as you asked

> How can he repent? Does he need to tell whom he lied to the truth? Or
>   is it enough to do istighfar?

It is declared that in regard to compensate for the sins such as lie, repenting is sufficient (by doing its steps (the steps of a real repentance). Of course there are some items who he should pay attention to, such as:

For instance, in case of accusing someone …, he/she ought to remove the negative accuse of that in front of the persons who he has lied about. (In order to remove its unreal… from the mind of others.)

He ought to confess to his/her lie in the cases which he has lied as a witness, in order to make up for his mistake (to regain the right of the person who was trampled by his lie speech). And some more related explanations that I endeavored to indicate some of them briefly.

---

**Conclusion:**

Based on your question concerning telling a small lie, the best way is repentance. In the meanwhile, you ought to compensate what you have trampled by telling that lie (as much as possible) by different ways such as informing the persons who … or even compensate or make up for the financial disadvantage if… / Besides, to the best of my knowledge, seemingly, you should not confess to that small lie IF confessing to that make you a more remarkable difficulty. (But as I stated, besides the repentance you should make up for the financial disadvantages or the items which led to discredit…

And Allah Know Best.

---

**References:**

- [www.pasokhgoo.ir](http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/19523)
- [akhlagh.porsemani.ir](http://akhlagh.porsemani.ir/node/665)

Comment: So if the lie didn't harm anybody, repentamce is just enough?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yeah. i.g. somebody asks what was your final exam mark, you reply X (as a minor sin). So, apparently it doesnt not harm the questioner in usual situation. Then repentance could be sufficient. (since as you mentioned, it has not made him/her any harm...). In the meanwhile, (I reckon in the mentioned item, repentance it sufficient, in order not to "declaring about your sin...) / Since as much as I know, the dissemination of the sins is counted as sin too (in the items which is not necessary to confess...).

Comment: Jazaka Allah khair brother, this pefectly answers my question.

Comment: I am at your service dear smart curious mate. But as an extra explanation (for all of us), we ought not to forget that persistence in minor sins makes them major sins. Although lie totally can be considered as a major sin anyhow / And we should not look at this as a minor sin..  و من الله توفیق

Comment: That is totally true.

Comment: How about if he lied about committing adultery to his friend . And now he looks bad in the sight of is friend. He regrets it. But he just want to just forget  it and hope his friend forgets It  too and move on. Should he tel his friend he didn't commit adultery?. Either way he looks bad..